# webpack html and file loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a Webpack loaders config which looks like this
`{ test: /\.html$/, loader: file!html!val!render-ect' }`
and I require an `html` file `require('./file.html')`.

`ect-render` gets file content and returns compiled html (from [ect](http://ectjs.com)).

I want to save compiled (and with resolved images that are supposed to be loaded through `file-loader` also) html to separate file. And it saves, but without images (from img:src attributes).

If I remove `file-loader` from html chain, images are being saved, but html is obviously not. What am I doing wrong? How do I resolve images inside html and save it into file another way?

Comment: And if I add another `val-loader` before `file-loader` like `file!val!html!val!render-ect`, images are somehow being considered as javascript code. I have no idea why this happens.